# CSS how to fill remaining space (1 div with smaller divs)

Tags: javascript, css

**[EDIT RE-OPEN 5-10]**
Im stil having the same issue! The main functions are all implemented now so i'm heading back to this issue. I Changed the Div's to an UL LI list as recommended.
But i still can't fill the whole area with products. Each product has a certain width and height.

*I'm making this for the Elo TouchSystems 1529L Monitor. With 6*10 products on the screen (left) and some information and options (right)(currently not in the image) It will run in Google Chrome Kiosk (fullscreen)*

Im trying to get some kind of grid as shown here (It is hard to see in the image, but there is a 1px white row at the bottom that im trying to get rid of. Black is end of screenheight)

[image: Current productarea]

@RenaatDeMuynck suggested to use the advanced CSS3 `grid or box-flex` since im only using Google Chrome.

Grid seems very powerfull and requires me to do some changes in code (thats fine) But before i go there, i want to be sure if im correct.

For grid i have to make rows? yes?
That means a list is unsuitable!

Does that mean i need to go back to my old strucute with divs and add rows?

**Old (with float:left;)**

```
<div products>
    <div product>info</div>
    <div product>info</div>
    <div product>info</div>
    <div product>info</div>
    ...etc
</div>
```

**New with Grid??**

```
<div products>
    <div row>
        <div product>info</div>
        <div product>info</div>
        <div product>info</div>
        ...etc
    </div>
    <div row>
        <div product>info</div>
        <div product>info</div>
        <div product>info</div>
        ...etc
    </div>
    ...etc
</div>
```

---

---

**[OLD Q]**

Im showing multiple 'product' **li** inside 1 'products' **ul**

```
for ( i = 0; i < totalProductsOnScreen; i++) {
    HTMLContent += "<li class=productDiv id=empty" + i + " onclick='#'></li>";
} 
document.getElementById("productsUL").innerHTML = (HTMLContent + "<div style='clear:both'></div>");
```

dont mention the id and onclick. Its something i fill up under this code

here is the **updated** CSS

```
#productsDiv {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.productDiv {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: outset;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    width: 16.66%;/*14.2857%;*/
    height: 10%;
    max-height: 10%;
}
```

The current code gives this: 
[postimage.org image](http://postimage.org/image/htli015xr/)
(had to be a link because as a beginner im not allowed to post images)

Its not very visible but at the very bottom there is 1 pixel unused in the productsDiv. (red color).
Thats not a big deal. But when im zooming in and out it changes. Sometimes its 4 pixels unused or its 2 pixels to much. So i want to solve this by giving the last row of productDiv's the remaining height.

How can i accomplish that?

Comment: Your data structure will be better understood from semanthic point of view if you use a list <ul> of products <li>s.

Comment: Well you are probably right with that. Now its just a long line of divs, automaticly positioned by the browser. Thanks for the tip. I will change that! But does that solves the problem?

Comment: Actually not, but is won't get things worse. Just your CSS should be a bit different and your HTML will be more understandable by all devices.

Comment: oke, So what would you suggest? a list of row lists? <ul><li>rowlist</li><li>rowlist</li><li>rowlist</li><ul>or 1 big list with al items <ul><li>product</li><li>product</li><li>product</li><ul>

Comment: <ul><li>product</li><li>product</li><li>product</li><ul> definitively

Comment: That wasn't so hard to change ;) little bit of css problems, needed to delete the ul/li style, thats solved now! Only the issue is remaining. I cant upvote your comments yet. think because im new here!

Comment: I agree, it should be a list of li's. But I wouldn't suggest both refactoring and fixing the problem at the same time.

Comment: Try to avoid using percentages. It may look good at 100% but when zooming, they will almost always give rounding errors. I would recommend using pixels or em's. Set the width to a multiple of 6 if you want 6 products to fit nicely in one row (i.e. 6 * 100px = 600px)

Comment: @RenaatDeMuynck That means the height will be 768px/10products = 76.8 px (4.518em)? I will get into that! thnx

Comment: Oke, I changed % to px/em And gave the productarea a width of 720px (6x120), the height however is max 768 (screen limit). (10x) 76.8 px or 4.518em don't seem to work.

Comment: You cannot use fractions with pixels, so you have to use 76px. Em's are a little more difficult to calculate because it is relative to the font size. But why do you want the parent to be max 768px? Screen limits are never the same on different devices, browsers or zoom levels.

Comment: I'm making this for the [Elo TouchSystems 1529L Monitor](http://www.elotouch.com/Products/LCDs/1529L/default.asp). With 6*10 products on the screen (left) and some information and options (right)
It will run in Google Chrome Kiosk (fullscreen)

Comment: @Marcel Ok, that explains a lot :-). Since you are just using Chrome maybe you could use some advanced CSS3 techniques (I'm thinking `grid` or `box-flex`). I'll get back to you.

Comment: @RenaatDeMuynck Im using Google Chrome for the advanced techniques, mostly local Storage and the HTML5 File System.. Cool, i never heard of those! Grid seems very powerfull but requires me to do some changes in code (thats fine) But before i go there, i want to be sure if im correct. Ill update the main post, so give me a sec ;)

Comment: Fixed with box [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/264Gx/2/)

Comment: And this brings me to the next problem! box width is flexible and messing up the entire table. If the content inside a product div is bigger, it will resize to make a better fit.

Comment: I see you beat me to it but i think i have a better solution. I've posted my final solution as an answer. it has a cleaner markup and uses the new spec for flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

`height:100%;` in the row css
`width:100%` in the product css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2Ya8/31/) that shows this! http://jsfiddle.net/h2Ya8/31/

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `height` means 'inner height', not 'outer height'. The height of your products is the result of height + margin-top + margin-bottom. Since you fix both content and container height, they won't always fit.

If you want your container to be 100% covered by your content, don't fix its height.

Keep in mind that since productsDiv only contains floated objects it might not have height in some browsers. You might need to hack a little. A well known is `zoom: 1; overflow: auto`, but it sometimes introduces an scroll bar. More here: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/clear-float-overflow-auto/

Comment: So your saying i dont need to fix the height of the productsDiv. Or do you mean i dont need to fix the contents height. Im playing around with the heights and overflow like you said, but its doing all sort of strange things.

Comment: Adding `zoom: 1; overflow: auto;` gives a scroll bar :S

Comment: I mean you probably shouldn't fix the height of productsDiv, let it grow as content does.

Comment: Im getting an scroll bar. So thats not the solution for me than! You say i must let the content grow. The thing im trying to accomplish says the opposite. I need 60 products! (later mayby less or more) 6 products in width and 10 products in height. All the productDiv's need to have the same width and height. So they dont grow! So i thought it could be solved with a different style in the last row of products. Or am I completely wrong? (I appreciate all the effort you've put in here)

Comment: Don't try to fix everything. Fix both width and height of the product, and fix the width of the container. That will generate the matrix you need. And, if you need the container to be visible, instead of the `zoom` hack, append this after your last product: `<div style="clear:both"></div>`

Comment: I'm still having this issue! (updated main post with information)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `zoom: 1; overflow: hidden;` will also work and will eliminate the scroll bars. Setting a fixed width and height on you parent div is NOT a good solution in my opinion. Certainly not if the number of products will change in the future. A fixed height will also most probably break when zooming (which was your problem in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

This is my final solution. It uses the new W3C definition of flexbox (as of August 2012, only supported in Chrome 21+)

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="products">
  <li>product 1</li>
  <li>product 2</li>
  <li>product 3</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>product n</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

ul.grid {
  /*  As of August 2012, only supported in Chrome 21+ */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  background: silver;
}

ul.grid > li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 98px; /* (600px / 6) - 2px for the borders  */
  overflow: hidden;
  border: outset 1px;
}

ul.grid > li.food {
  background-image: url(images/food.png);
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/unGrt

Comment: Works very nice, Zooming (also in your final solution) still results in strange behavior.. next issue with this (is it ok to go further in this question or is this off topic?)
when i want to add content to the li's it seems there are no limits in width and height. (say i want to fill the li entirely with a picture)

Comment: Hmm, I forgot to test zooming. In my opinion it's a rendering bug though, it's still experimental (I might post a bug report at Webkit :-)). For the background stretching CSS3 comes to the rescue again: `background-size: 100%`

Comment: I really like your solution! it's very clean, however it still does not solve (on this moment) the zooming issue. Plus the width has to be calculated! Whenever my client want to change te total products in width from 6 to 5 (or 6 to 7) the CSS has to change completely. So i did some testing and i really like the box-flex with rows as it fills up all the space in every zoom. Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2Ya8/6/) . New problem with current solution (new question). [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777295/css3-box-how-to-stop-automatic-resize-with-content)

Comment: Found the solution!! [other topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777295/css3-box-how-to-stop-automatic-resize-with-content/12779166#12779166)