# CSS3 Box, How to stop automatic resize with content?

Tags: html, css

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2Ya8/6/) to see my problem in action! http://jsfiddle.net/h2Ya8/6/
Related to [CSS how to fill remaining space (1 div with smaller divs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489918/css-how-to-fill-remaining-space-1-div-with-smaller-divs/)

**I am only using/testing this for Google Chrome, as it's going to run on a machine with Google Chrome**

I have 10 rows with each 6 boxes. These boxes take up all the space available.
It works fine when i'm only putting content that fits in the box. But when the content is bigger than the box can handle, the boxes resize to fit the content.

I want to stop the boxes from resizing and always stay the same, no matter what content is put in.
(currently i'm using div with div's but i want to replace this with box as it automaticly fills up the space available, )
(i need to fill these boxes with images and text)

Current output with Div's
[image: Products in a cashdesk]

Comment: nothing is resizing for me? all are fixed..which div is changing it's size?

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention it's an webapp specially for Google Chrome!
The red boxes are resized to fit the content.

Comment: new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2Ya8/13/) to clarify

Comment: @Marcel Only a question... Why instead of using so maaaany divs don't use a table or a list? It would be easier for you to modify, and your problems will decrease exponentially...

Comment: @Sonhja Because this solves my previous issue: remaining space left at the bottom of a list! (link to Question at top of post). As you can see! I did used a list <ul> <li> there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution!

`height:100%;` in the row css
`width:100%` in the product css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2Ya8/31/) that shows this! http://jsfiddle.net/h2Ya8/31/

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You only specify that the page as whole is of a certain size:

```
 #page {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
}
```

If you want the "boxes", here the `<div class="product">` to have a fixed size you should set the CSS for it to something like:

```
 .product {
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    border: etc...;
```

Comment: @Mr.Alien you are totally right! The width and height arn't fixed sizes! Alex: Whenever you zoom in or out the width and height always change a bit. The CSS3 Box handles this. Im using this solution as it fixes my previous problem ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489918/css-how-to-fill-remaining-space-1-div-with-smaller-divs/) to related question)

Answer (score 0):

You just specify width and height to #page: overflow:auto.

i.e,

```
#page {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: a box specifies the width and height automaticly. Do you mean i have to guess the size?